# php input filtering, unwanted slashes in get and post params

Tags: php, filtering

How can I disable input filtering?

Here is an example:

```php
echo "\$_GET: ";
var_dump($_GET);

echo "filter.default: ";
var_dump(ini_get('filter.default'));
echo "filter.default_flags: ";
var_dump(ini_get('filter.default_flags'));

echo "\nCurrent PHP version: " . phpversion() . "\n";
```

When I test it with this url: `http://example.org/?text=<a href="http://example.org">...</a>` the code generate this:

```
$_GET: array(1) {
  ["text"]=>
  string(38) "<a href=\"http://example.org\">...</a>"
}
filter.default: string(1) "0"
filter.default_flags: bool(false)

Current PHP version: 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.7
```

Server info:

```
System  Linux magentob.builder.hu 2.6.31-14-server #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 16 15:07:34 UTC 2009 x86_64 
This server is protected with the Suhosin Patch 0.9.7
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend Engine v2.2.0
Loaded Modules:     core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_expires mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_ssl mod_status mod_vhost_alias
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to disable `magic_quotes` which is disabled by default as of php 5.3.0 and removed as of 5.4.0

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Edit: guide on disabling http://www.ecommerceoffice.com/enabling-disabling-magic-quotes-in-php/

Comment: thx @dirt, it works